# error occurs rendering and expanded - column widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, rendering, chat

I'm getting a lot of errors regarding the rendering and I think its the way I'm using column and expanded and scroll view but i cant figure out how to fix it, I've tried different solutions but it still produces different errors

```
 (elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class
 _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch) The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
 RenderFlex#357da relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
 NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE RenderObject: RenderFlex#357da
 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
 NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
     needs compositing
 
 child 1: RenderPositionedBox#2911a relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
 NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
         parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
         constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
         size: Size(392.7, 36.0)
         alignment: Alignment.center
         textDirection: ltr
         widthFactor: expand
         heightFactor: expand
         child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#3a796 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
             parentData: offset=Offset(178.4, 0.0) (can use size)
             constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
             size: Size(36.0, 36.0)
             child: RenderConstrainedBox#b58da relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE parentData: <none> (can use
 size)
                 constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
                 size: Size(36.0, 36.0)
                 additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(36.0<=w<=Infinity, 36.0<=h<=Infinity)
                 child: RenderCustomPaint#a2388 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
                     parentData: <none> (can use size)
                     constraints: BoxConstraints(36.0<=w<=392.7, 36.0<=h<=Infinity)
                     size: Size(36.0, 36.0)
                     painter: _CircularProgressIndicatorPainter#971dd()
```

and there is more like this

and these are the errors that i get

> The relevant error-causing widget was SingleChildScrollView
> The relevant error-causing widget was Container The relevant
> error-causing widget was Scaffold
>
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 1840 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true. The relevant
> error-causing widget was Column

and its like along list of errors like these

this is chatScreen class

```
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final String chatWithName;
  final Future<bool> flag;
  ChatScreen(this.chatWithName, this.flag);
  

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(chatWithName), centerTitle: true,),

      body: Container(
        height: 200,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            //  Expanded(
            //    child: messages()),
               messages(),
              newMessage(flag),
          ],
        ) ,

        )
        ),
       
    );
  }
}
```

this is in class newMessage

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _enterdMessage = value;
              });
            },
          )
          ),
          IconButton(
              //onPressed: _enterdMessage.trim().isEmpty ? null : _sendMessage,
              onPressed: (){
                if(_enterdMessage.trim().isEmpty == true){
                  return null;
                }
                else{
                  if(widget.roomExist==true){
                    notFirstTime();
                  }else{
                    if(widget.roomExist==false){
                    firstTime();
                  }
                  }
                }
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.send))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is class messages

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder<User>(
        future: Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser),
        builder: (context, futureSnapshot){
          if(futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
           return StreamBuilder <QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('chats').orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder:(ctx, chatSnapshot){
      if(chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
      final chatdocs = chatSnapshot.data!.docs;
      
      //i think here is where we check if they have the same roomid or not
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        reverse: true,
        itemCount: chatdocs.length, 
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => messageBubble(
          chatdocs[index]['text'],
          chatdocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data!.uid, //this is the error- udemy 335 minute 7:26
          //chatdocs[index]['username'],
          ),
          
        
        );
        }
        );
    } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use multiple scrollable widget for this case. the parent widget(SingleChildScroll) already hadling the scroll event. You can return column instead of ListView widget from streamBuilder. A better option will be using CustomChildScrollView.

```
return  Column(
  children:  List.generate(chatdocs.length, (index) => messageBubble(
    chatdocs[index]['text'],
    chatdocs[index]['userId'] == futureSnapshot.data?.uid, //this is the error- udemy 335 minute 7:26
    //chatdocs[index]['username'],
    ),),
);
```

Comment: this solution removed the errors but the textfield from class newMessage is not visible

Comment: try to check if it is getting data properly,  like on `chatdocs`